# Playing video on flutter app on android using better_player is causing this error

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

> Non-fatal Exception:
> io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError:
> PlatformException(error,
> MediaSource.Factory#setDrmSessionManagerProvider no longer handles
> null by instantiating a new DefaultDrmSessionManagerProvider.
> Explicitly construct and pass an instance in order to retain the old
> behavior., null, java.lang.NullPointerException:
> MediaSource.Factory#setDrmSessionManagerProvider no longer handles
> null by instantiating a new DefaultDrmSessionManagerProvider.
> Explicitly construct and pass an instance in order to retain the old
> behavior.

It was working previously but now it's failing due to exoPlayer. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

it happened when i added another audio package to pubpsec.yaml  so i removed last added audio package and  run flutter clean then it worked fine again

Answer (score 2):

If you have `chewie` or `video_player` added in project, then remove them and try.

Answer (score 2):

Someone made a fix for this in this issue but it's still not merged.  [Update and fixed BUG java.lang.NullPointerException: MediaSource.Factory#setDrmSessionManagerProvider #1085](https://github.com/jhomlala/betterplayer/pull/1085)

Comment: save me lot of time thank you

Answer (score -1):

for the Android error, it tells you that you need to enable multiDex in your project, here is how

in `android/app/build.gradle` add this line `multiDexEnabled = true` in the `defaultConfig`

your defaultConfig should look something like this

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.test.test"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    multiDexEnabled = true
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

regarding the iOS error it says

dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

so increase the minimum deployment target. you can find it in `ios/flutter/AppFrameworkInfo.plist` named `MinimumOSVersion` and looking like this

```
<key>MinimumOSVersion</key> 
<string>9.0</string>
```